# Magento 2 Rest auth for different website ids

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, multi-website, authorize

I'm getting customer auth token with following REST request

```
http://mage.local/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
```

It is working fine for customers with website_id = 1, but not works for other website_id.

How should I set website_id in my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how I can log in for a specific store. 
**default** in the request is actually store code

```
http://mage.local/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token
```

So to log in for a different store you need to put another store code, like

```
http://mage.local/rest/STORE_CODE_HERE/V1/integration/customer/token
```